# If B1=empty how to make A1=empty by script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The following Google Apps Script is intended to implement this logic for each row of a spreadsheet:

```
If (column B is empty)
  Then: set column A empty
```

Here is the non-working code I have so far:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var colS = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues(); // col2 row1       
var ColD = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();  // col1 row 1 targeted to delete


    for (var i = 0; i < columnS.length; i++)
    if (colS[i][0] == '')
      {
      var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').setActiveSelection(colD[i]);
        aa.clear({ formatOnly: true, contentsOnly: true });
      }
    else
      {
      return
      }
    }
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code bellow:

```
function resetValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');     
  var colS = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues(); // col2 row1    

  for (var i = 1; i < colS.length; i++) {
    if (colS[i-1][0] == '') {      
      sheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue("");      
    }    
  }
}
```

Maybe your code is not working because:

1. If you don't match the if condition you are breaking the for loop.
2. columnS is a variable that is not defined.

Live version of my code can be found [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1xx6Z4shcwSF4G37Vn9V4buYKTd5wLfI__Crj07S-cQuP4I6RH7qOm07h/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: That was perfect! You've my gratitude! :-)

Comment: One more query, If colK need to delete shall i use 
if (colS[i+9][0] == '') ??

Comment: Do you want to delete colK of colK will be your condition?

Comment: if (colS[i-1][1] == '') {      
      sheet.getRange(i, 11).setValue("");      
    }

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! :-)